# How does a Bless Spell work when cast on items?

Tags: spells, adnd-2e

A Bless spell can be cast upon an item to make it blessed. Examples would be a blessed finely cured piece of leather for an Armor spell or a blessed crossbow to slay a Rakshasa.  I'm not clear about how Bless spell applies to items used in this nature.

Does the blessing last only as long as the spell, requiring a cleric to cast a bless spell prior to those items being used?  Or can you just cast a bless spell on a piece of leather or crossbow bolt and it's considered blessed from then on?

Furthermore, how many items can you bless with a spell at one time, since bless is usually an area effect spell that boosts allies? Can it be cast on a pile of leather scraps and crossbow bolts or only one at a time?

I don't see where it's clear in how to use bless when required for reasons other than blessing the party.

Answer (score 1):

The text on Bless is pretty explicit.

> A second use of this spell is to bless a single item (for example, a crossbow bolt for use against a rakshasa). The weight of the item is limited to one pound per caster level and the effect lasts until the item is used or the spell duration ends.

You Bless *one* crossbow bolt, scrap of leather, etc that is no larger than 1lb per caster level. It remains Blessed until used for its purpose or 6 rounds.

Comment: It sounds like *used* here may mean that the caster must also pick the purpose of the *bless* spell. That is, if you *bless* a candle you have to say, "I *bless* this candle so that it wards away evil spirits," then while it's lit and until it's exhausted it does (if that's a thing), but if you just say, "I *bless* this candle," then it lasts the spell's normal duration. Is that accurate or am I overreading again?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think you are over-reading. There are things that care if an item is blessed, but nothing I am aware of that imputes via expectation a specific purpose onto the blessing of blessed objects.